# How to work with a Boolean function in C in this code

Tags: c, boolean

What is wrong in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool func(char *, int);

void main()
{
   char *a = "Interview";
   if(func(a, 9))
   {
      printf("True");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("False");
   }
}

bool func(char *s, int len)
{
   if(len < 2)
      return true;
   else
      return s[0] == s[len-1] && func(&s[1], len-2);
}
```

I believe this function always returns `TRUE`. This is an interview question. But, when I try to compile this, it shows six errors...

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdbool.h>`. The return type of `main` shall be `int`.

Comment: you may use int instead of bool and 1/0 instead of true/false. or #define bool int, #define true 1, #define false 0

Comment: syntax error : identifier 'func'

Comment: @JX yes i may, but it was an interview question.. so i can't make any correction on that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going to guess it doesn't know what `bool` and `true` are. `bool` is not a primitive data type in C. You need an extra include:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

The second part of your question? *Does it always return TRUE?*

No:

When you come into the function, you'll skip the first return because your length is 9. So instead you'll return if `true` only if:

```
return s[0] == s[len-1] && func(&s[1], len-2)
```

Is true. You can skip the recursive logic here because it's not modifying your string. Just look at the first part:

```
s[0]     // This has to be 'I'
==       // We need so what we compare against has to be 'I' as well
s[len-1] // This will be 'w'
```

So... that's not going to return true... Who cares about ANDing (`&&`) the recursive part? I suspect the compiler will even optimize that out because everything here is hard coded.

Comment: Correction, bool is not a primitive data type, but it is standard in C99 and following(hence stdbool )

Comment: please correct me... the particular function will always return `TRUE` or not??

Comment: because... `s[len-1] && func(&s[1], len-2);` at last `func(&s[1], len-2);` return `TRUE`, which means it become  `s[len-1] && true` and anything except `0` is also known as `TRUE`. so thats why. pls correct me. if my logic is wrong.

Comment: @coders -  right... so `s[len-1] && true` will be true, but it doesn't end there... you need to have `s[0] == s[len-1]` for it to be true as well. That can't happen. Check out the edit to my post regarding the logic

Comment: @Mike thanks !! but program showing error.`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory` why so.. ??

Comment: +1 and accepted for best explanation. :) but, @Mike, getting error. pls help.

Comment: @coders - Well that might be a different topic altogether. Are you on windows or Linux? What IDE? etc. I'm going to recomend you do a few searchs and if you can't find an answer open up another topic. If you're using Linux try searching from root for stdbool.h with: `sudo find . -name "stdbool.h"`. Then make sure it's included correctly, it should be in `/usr/include`

Comment: ok... i'm using `Windows`. but as you said, it belongs to different topic. So, i will search it on google. And, i hope, i will find something helpful there :-)

Answer (score 6):

You just have to include the right header.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Or, you can use `_Bool` type, which don't need any inclusion. `bool` is just an alias from this type. By the way, don't forget to compile in C99.

Answer (score -2):

true and false are defined as 1 and 0, so you should do this:

```c
#define true 1
#define false 0
int code() {
  //code
}
```

Comment: Re *"true and false are defined as 1 and 0"*: Do you have a source?